# Does JAX-RS/Jersey 2.x utilize servlet 3.0 async capability?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jsr311

Does JAX-RS/Jersey 2.x utilize servlet 3.0 async capability? or it is just another async layer on top of old-fashioned thread/request based servlet architecture.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understand, async in Jersey will come in version 2.0 (mostly the implementation of JAX-RS 2.0). Look at the current status [on the project](http://jersey.java.net/):

> Currently we are working full speed on Jersey 2.0 which will implement
>   JAX-RS 2.0. Milestone builds are available from maven central
>   repository. You can see the latest snapshot of Jersey 2.0 API
>   documentation [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/index.html). More information can be found on [Jersey 2.0 Status page](http://jersey.java.net/jersey20.html).

Looking at the documentation, you may find [AsyncResponse](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/index.html?javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html), which is a good start, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey supports various containers. When running on Servlet 3.x it utilizes the async servlet capability to implement the async API. When running on Grizzly, it utilizes the Grizzly NIO API.